# Creation of single column view from three multiple table columns

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I create view with single column by using three different table columns?
For example drug_name from table drug, synonym column from drug_info table and brand column from drug_b tables in single column?

Answer (score 2):

```
select drug_name from drug 
union
select synonym from drug_info 
union
select brandfrom drug_b tables
```